# Eigenvalues - useful for stability detection of nonlinear systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm using a software tool for modeling biochemical system expressed with a system of nonlinear ODEs. The tool has functionality for finding a "steady state" of the system, as well as the Jacobian matrix and its eigenvalues.

For a linear system, having an eigenvalue with positive real part means that the steady state of the system is unstable. However, the systems I'm interested in are not linear and have many reactions (= equations).

The documentation of the software says that "the stability analysis is linear. The stability analysis is always performed in a steady state. The jacobian is basically a linearization of the system around the steady state (the jacobian is calculated by numerical differentiation of the differential equations)." Does that mean that having a positive eigenvalue is a reliable indicator of instability?

Comment: Yes, for perturbations of autonomous systems $x'=Ax$. Certainly not for nonautonomous systems $x'=A(t)x$.

Comment: Should be autonomous. The equations describe chemical reactions and depend only on variable concentration changes during time, not explicitly on time.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is then the following. Say that you have a differential equation $x'=f(x)$ with $f$ of class $C^1$. Assume now that $f(x_0)=0$ and that $d_{x_0}f$ has an eigenvalue with positive real part. Then there exists a unstable invariant manifold of the dynamics defined by $x'=f(x)$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ (tangent to the unstable subspace of the dynamics $x'=Ax$, where $A=d_{x_0}f$. So, in particular, the solution $x_0$ is unstable.